# UITableView value keep changing while moving

Tags: iphone

I have configured a table view cell, whose tables cell is loaded from another xib, both the filename and the identities are called,BlogViewControllerTableCell
Most of them works properly, but some contents in the cells keep changing while scrolling.
No matter I use the array value, or simply put the [indexpath row].

The below is the code,
I would be appreciate for your help.
Thanks.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BlogViewControllerTableCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BlogViewControllerTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    student_name.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[student_list objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"name"]];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You aren't changing any cell value in these lines.

Comment: student_name is not coming from cell??

Comment: 1. we need to know what is student_name. Is it an IBOutlet into where you load the xib of the cell?? 2. stringWithFormat:@"%@" is completely useless 3. if the cell contents are changing it is surely because you return the cells to slowly, and they become reused before your update process could finish.